# TYPO3, RealURL, shortcuts and multiple languages = no joy

Tags: ssl, typo3, realurl

I am trying to get RealURL working on my TYPO3 4.7 installation. The complete site is SSL encrypted. Here's my config:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
  'pagePath' => array(
    'type' => 'user',
    'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
    'segTitleFieldList' => 'tx_realurl_pathsegment,alias,title,nav_title',
    'languageGetVar' => 'L',
  ),
  'preVars' => array(
    array(
      'GETvar' => 'L',
      'valueMap' => array(
          'en' => '0',
          'de' => '1',
      ),
      'noMatch' => 'bypass',
    ),
  ),
);
```

My page tree has category pages that each link to the first subpage:

```
Home
Cat1 [shortcut]
 | 
 --subpage1.1
 --subpage1.2
Cat2 [shortcut]
 |
 --subpage2.1
 --subpage2.2
Cat3
[..]
External link
```

Everything works fine as long as I am using the default language (English). As soon as I switch to language 1 (German) the Cat links disappear which makes it impossible to reach the subpages. Entering the subpage URL directly, e.g. https://domain.com/cat1/subpage1.1 takes me to the desired page. Oh, and the external link is broken, too, though that is a minor issue.
The titles, subtitles, nav titles and speaking urls are set for both languages. I also tried changing "first available subpage" to a fixed subpage, but that did not improve the situation.

Edit: "links disappear" means that the nav menu displays correctly, but the respective a tags do not have an href attribute. E.g. the English version has a

```
<li><a href="en/cat1/subpage1.1/" onfocus="blurLink(this);"  >Cat1</a></li>
```

nav element whereas the German version has

```
<li><a onfocus="blurLink(this);"  >Cat1</a></li>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use CoolUri, better experience ;) and easy to add languages

Comment: I have circumvented the issue by downgrading to Typo3 4.5